# How to use malloc and free in 64-bit NASM?

Tags: assembly, malloc, nasm, x86-64, free

In 64-bit NASM, I'm allocating a memory block of 8000 bytes using malloc() from the C library, and when I'm finished with it, I deallocate it by calling free().

My research has come up with a lot of conflicting information about how to do this in 64-bit NASM, and much of the information is 32-bit, where the calling convention is different, or it's C or C++, not NASM.

I think I have the malloc part right, but I'm not sure about the free part.  I'm posting this question because I don't want to test it and have a memory block allocated but not freed.

So my two questions are simple:
    (1) do I have this right for 64-bit NASM?
    (2) is the syntax the same for Windows and Linux?

I'm showing only the malloc and free parts of my program:

```
extern malloc
extern free

push rdi

; Allocate the memory buffer
mov rdi,8000
call malloc
mov [array_pointer],rax ;array_pointer is initialized in .data

; Code that uses the buffer goes here.  

; Free the memory buffer
push rdi
call free
add rsp,8

pop rdi
ret
```

Comment: `malloc` returns the pointer in _RAX_. You need to move _RAX_ to _RDI_ (or move the address stored at `array_pointer`to _RDI_) to free it (as the first parameter to `free` is passed via _RDI_ like every function that conforms to the 64-bit System V ABI). You also don't need the `push rdi` and `add rsp, 8` around the `call free`. Doing so will mess up stack alignment.

Comment: If you are writing native Windows code in assembly this will not work since the 64-bit Windows Calling convention is different than Linux. Under Windows RCX, RDX, R8, and R9. are used to pass integer/pointer arguments. That is different than Linux which uses RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R8, R9. You can read about the differences here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Comment: Thanks, Michael.  I'm doing this first for Windows.  If I move the pointer to RDI to call free, this will not work in Windows?

Comment: If you are writing this for Native Windows you pass the first parameter in RCX and not RDI. Return values will be in RAX for boith Linux and Windows. The 64-bit Windows convention can be found at the link I gave above.More info is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx

Comment: If you are writing code for WSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux) that isn't native Windows and follows the 64-bit Linux System V ABI - so is the same as Linux. This is because WSL is 64-bit Linux.

Comment: I know the Windows calling convention for passing parameters to a DLL; are you saying that I need call free differently for Windows than you show in your first comment?

Comment: In *64-bit code* the calling convention for DLLs and regular code is the same. In 64-bit code Microsoft standardized on a single 64-bit calling convention as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx . Rather than using RDI to pass the first parameter to `malloc` or `free` you need to use _RCX_ instead of _RDI_.

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up.  You say the "first parameter" to free -- I assume there is only one parameter for free, the pointer to the memory block?

Comment: The _C_ library is standardized. You can find all the functions and their parameters at the cppreference site. The memory functions can be found here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory . Whether called from _C_ or assembly `free` takes a single parameter (the pointer) and has no return value. .`malloc` takes a single parameter (the size in bytes) and returns a pointer (in _RAX_).The index for the _C_ library on cpp reference is here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c

Comment: Thanks very much.  I think that confirms everything I need to know.  You've been a big help.

Comment: Pay particular attention to the "scratch space"/"shadow space" that the Windows 64-bit ABI dictates. This is a common source of crashes when trying simple 64-bit Windows assembly. You're technically supposed to be allocating this space for all "non-leaf" functions... so I imagine that also means when calling into C library functions ... even if they don't make use of the allocated space. The link Michael provides does say "must always provide space" and so I've personally always run with that assumption as well.

Comment: Also have to pay attention to the stack alignment. It needs to be 16-byte aligned at the point a function call is made. By the time the call of a function is done you not only need to sure there are 32-bytes allocated for the scratch h space you also need to ensure that stack space starts on a 16-byte aligned address. After your function starts pushing any value (like RBP) will realign to such a 16 byte boundary

Comment: I think we do that by sub rsp,32 just before the call.  That would keep it 16-byte aligned.

Comment: No, it's not. Before a function call the stack will be 16 byte aligned. The `call` itself misaligns the stack by 8 bytes (it piushes the return address on the stack). This means that when the first instruction starts executing in your function you have an unaligned stack. To realign it to 16-bytes you need at a minimum an 8 byte adjustment to  realign to 16-bytes You'll then need to make sure that any space for locals maintains that 16-byte alignment so that by the time you adjust RSP to account for the 32 bytes required for the scratch space.

Comment: If you have a function with no local variables, you would need adjust the stack by a total of 40 bytes before calling another function. 8 bytes torealign + 32 bytes for scratch space.

Comment: @RTC222 a very very basic prologue will re-align the stack for you. So as Michael says, upon entering a function the stack is misaligned. A simple `push rbp` (+ `mov rbp,rsp` if thats your style) prologue will then re-align it for you. That's when you can begin thinking about scratch space and local variable allocation. Noting of course that this completely ignores `UNWIND_INFO`/exception handling... but that's a whole other story...

Comment: Usually the way I do it (without a stack frame and not worrying about unwinding) is subtract 40 bytes + (number of bytes needed for locals (a size rounded up to nearest 16)) from RSP.. at the beginning of the function. This means in one instruction I realign to a 16 byte boiundary, allocate all the local space,and allocate the scratch space all at once. The advantage is that I don't need to worry about alignment (and scratch space) at any point in my function since I've already ensured all that is allocated and stack aligned at the start. My local varaiables would then start at RSP+32.

Comment: In that aboive scenario I have to also account for any of the non-volatile registers I need to push and pop before the local variables. If I push an odd number of 64-bit registers that will naturally realign the stackto 16-bytes. An even number of pushes would be out of alignment by 8 bytes so has to be accounted for in the value I subtract from RSP afterwards.

Comment: @Simon Whitehead, if I push 8 bytes on the stack after the call, that would re-align it, but I think it would be best to sub rsp,40 right before the call, as Michael Petch says.  That way I do both at once, and after the call I can add rsp,32.  Does it make sense to do it that way?

Comment: It doesn't really matter how you do it (if performance isn't an issue) as long as you understand the method you choose and the alignment is maintained. You don't actually physically add 32 to RSP to access local variables with my method. Local variables would start at memory addresses [RSP+32] as the 32 bytes of scratch space are at [RSP+0].

Comment: The latest version at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/overview-of-x64-calling-conventions says malloc is "aligned to 16 bytes in order to aid performance."  That suggests that I do not need to align the stack for a call to malloc.  Maybe this is new, because the earlier version doesn't say that.

Comment: Incorect. `malloc` returns a 16-byte aligned address so if you use an instruction (Like SSE) that requires aligned access on that pointer then it won't fail. However, you still need to ensure the stack is 16-byte aligned prior to calling `malloc` and `free` (and any other conformant function using the Windows 64-bit Calling Convention) because those functions may use CPU instructions that require the proper stack alignment to run properly.If a function doesn't fail if the stack is misaligned don't assume that'll be the case in the future.

Comment: I often see people say "it works without proper alignment so it is good enough" and then later on they go looking for help when their code unexpectedly starts crashing and wonders why and we have to go back and say "alignment is important, there is a reason it is documented that way"

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  The return address is 8 bytes and I would have to subtract it from the stack.  I'm not sure what Microsoft means by that comment.

Comment: The reality is if you say "I don't need to align it" to call a Microsoft 64-bit ABI conformant function (which includes all of the _C_, library, calls to system DLLs etc) then you are already headed down the path of evil.You should be saying "how do I make sure the stack remains aligned before calling a function so I don't face issues later on?"

Comment: @RTC222 it means that the region of memory that has been allocated by `malloc` and returned has a starting address that is 16-byte aligned. It has nothing to do with the caller and you don't need to adjust the stack _after_ the call to `malloc` (that appears to be what you're implying here...? Which is incorrect.).

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with Windows x64. A single integer-sized parameter (as given to both `malloc` and `free`) is passed in the `rcx` register and an integer return value is put into the `rax` register.

The basic rule is to use `rcx`, `rdx`, `r8`, and `r9` for the first four integer parameters and the stack for any others. Non-integer parameters complicate things a little but, since there are none of those in the `malloc` or `free` calls, I won't cover it here. If you need more information, Microsoft has a good article over at [`X64 Calling Convention`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-160).

Hence simple code for allocating and immediately freeing a block would be something like, with AT&T syntax given in parentheses after comment, if different:

```
mov  rcx, 1000          ; Allocate a block (mov $1000, %rcx).
call malloc             ; Allocate, address returned in rax.

mov  rcx, rax           ; Address needed in rcx (mov %rax, %rcx).
call free               ; And free it.
```

Note that this example, and the one below, simply illustrate register usage, there's other things you need to consider as well, such as shadow space and alignment requirements.

---

Linux uses a different approach (though still with registers for efficiency). It uses the System V AMD64 ABI and, for this case, you'll find `rax` still used for the return value but `rdi` used for the argument.

This ABI draws its integer register set from `{ rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx, r8, r9 }` with any extra parameters passed on the stack.

So the code change for Linux would be fairly simple, using `rdi` instaed of `rcx`:

```
mov  rdi, 1000          ; Allocate a block (mov $1000, %rdi).
call malloc             ; Allocate, address returned in rax.

mov  rdi, rax           ; Address needed in rdi (mov %rax, %rdi).
call free               ; And free it.
```

---

Raymond Chen (of [The Old New Thing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/) fame) has a series on calling conventions that you may find interesting, starting [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040102-00/?p=41213).

Comment: Don't forget that Windows x64 has shadow space, i.e. functions can step on the 32 bytes above their return address.  If you used this with the code in the question, it could step on your own return address, since you omitted `sub rsp, 32` / `add rsp, 32` before / after.  (or 40 if you remove the otherwise useless push/pop of RDI - Windows and SysV both require 16-byte stack alignment.  malloc/free specifically are unlikely to fail from a misaligned stack, but in general that's an important part of calling functions.)  Very likely there's a duplicate somewhere...

Comment: One of Agner Fog's guides (https://www.agner.org/optimize/#manuals) is about calling conventions, and the differences between them on different OSes.

Answer (score -7):

Assembly language doesnt have a standard library.  So this is not an assembly langauge question necessarily this is I have a set of libraries that conform to this calling convention or made by X compiler and version with such and such settings.  And I want to link with and use those libraries from assembly language.  Well first and foremost just write it in that language and compile and save temps or compile to assembly, and start with that code.  Or disassemble such code to discover the calling convention and compare that to what you find when reading up on the calling convention for this target platform with this compiler.

If it is a system call and you want to do that directly, and not a library call then you need to read up on the system call interface for this platform and operating system, no reason to assume any two are the same (Linux, BSD, Windows, etc).  Nor that major versions of each are the same although they probably are...

then write your code to conform to whichever you found.