# How to align stack on call to malloc from NASM dll

Tags: assembly, dll, malloc, nasm, ctypes

I am calling a 64-bit NASM dll using Python CTypes.  The example below is a stripped-down version that simply allocates 80 bytes of memory using malloc, and returns.

Based on the replies to a post I made yesterday at [How to use malloc and free in 64-bit NASM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48672864/how-to-use-malloc-and-free-in-64-bit-nasm), I thought I could just subtract 40 bytes from rsp, call malloc, and add rsp,32 on return from malloc.  I thought malloc would pop the 8-byte return address off the stack on return, then I add the other 32 bytes to rsp and return from the DLL.  However, on entry to malloc, the stack frame is not 16-byte aligned, so that's where I think the problem is.

The error I get is "access violation writing 0x0000000000000000", so clearly I am writing into some memory not owned by my calling function.

I haven't found any information on what else I should do in this case to 16-byte align.

Here is the NASM code:

```
[BITS 64]

export CallTest_fn

extern malloc

section .data align=16
temp_var: dq 1534.76
counter: dq 0
sizeof_array: dq 80
array_pointer: dq 0

section .text

;__________

CallTest_fn:
push rdi
push rbp

; Allocate memory buffer
mov rcx,qword[sizeof_array]
xor rax,rax
sub rsp,40
call malloc
add rsp,32

pop rbp
pop rdi
ret
```

The vars in the .data section and the push-pop sequence at start and end are for later use, but I kept them here.

Here is the Python ctypes code:

```
hDLL = ctypes.WinDLL(r"C:/NASM_Test_Projects/Test_Malloc_Return/Test_Malloc_Return.dll")
CallTest = hDLL.CallTest_fn
CallTest.restype = ctypes.c_int64

ret_ptr = CallTest()  #call the dll
```

Thanks very much for any help on this.

Comment: why are you using `add rsp,32`? Since you are leaving your function at that point you need to restore the stack the way it was upon entry. You subtracted 40 now you need to add 40 (not 32).

Comment: Thanks, Michael.  As I said, I thought the other 8 bytes were the return address and they are popped from the stack before exit.  If that's not correct, what are the 8 bytes for?

Comment: I just changed the code to read add rsp,40 and, as you said, it works correctly now.  Thank you.  But I'm still curious about what the other 8 bytes are for.

Comment: The `call` instruction pushes the return address on the stack. `ret` does the reverse (it pops the return address off). You have tomake sure the stack in between is maintained. The pushes have to be matched with the pops (in reverse order)and any space you allocate by subtracting from RSP has to be added back yourself.

Comment: What extra 8 bytes are you referring to?

Comment: If you are referring to why you subtract 40 and not 32. The reason is simple.You have tomake sure the stack is 16-byte aligned before calling malloc. So the `call`instruction that reached your function `CallTest_fn` put 8 bytes on the stack. The two pushes put 16 more bytes on. You need to subtract a number from RSP that can hold the 32 byte scratch space and makes the total bytes on the stack divisible by 16. 8+16+40=64 which is evenly divisible by 16. If you had subtracted 32 instead it would have been 8+16+32=56 which is not evenly divisible by 16.

Comment: The stack needs to be 16-byte aligned before calling malloc or any of the _C_ library (or any function conforming to the 64-bit Microsoft ABI)

Comment: Since you are not changing _RDI_ in this function(at least in this code) there is no need to push and pop it. If you remove it you would then have to subtract 32 (and not 40). You'd have 8 bytes pushed on the stack by the call to `CallTest_fn` + 8 bytes for pushing RBP + a number big enough to hold the scratch space and keeps the stack evenly divisible by 16. In that case the value is 32 to subtract. 8+8+32=48 which is evenly divisible by 16.

Comment: You really should consider learning assembly without Python. Once you understand how things work with just assembly move to using Python and assembly.

Comment: I think my misunderstanding was I thought the 8 bytes were for malloc's return address (when malloc returns to my caller), but malloc manages it's own return address.  Now you've clarified it.  I am pushing rdi because this is part of a larger program and I will be using it later -- I wanted it in here to be sure this program shows everything that will be set up before the call to malloc.

Comment: I am calling from ctypes because my purpose is to write dlls to call from ctypes.  I need to work out the details by calling from Python.